# php $_GET item to virtual subdomain with Htaccess

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess, subdomain, echo

I have a simple question that is related to **php** and **htaccess**.

Just think i have this php code :

```
if(isset($_GET['word'])) {
echo $_GET['word'];
}
```

So i will have this (for example) :

> example.com/?word=test

And the code with echo out `**test**`, So my question is that,

How can i change that **$_GET** value, to a **virtual subdomain** ?

For example, i want to have this, if this below address opened :

> test.example.com

then the code gets run and echo out `**test**`.

**I need a htaccess code to do this thing,** So, How can i do it with htaccess ?

i have tried some codes but i couldn't get results .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+) [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(?:^|&)word=[^&]+(?:&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?word=%1 [QSA,L]
```

`%1` is back reference to value captured in this line: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+) [NC]` which is first part of domain name before DOT.

Comment: there is no diffrence what i want to get, I need when for example `test.example.com` gets open, then my code gets run and page loads. Can u please check your ht code in your host or local to test it ? it's not really working :((

Comment: I don't post an answer without testing. This is fully tested and working rule. You need to provide straight answers to my questions. 1) Are there more rules in your .htaccess? 2) What is location of your .htaccess? 3) What does `echo $_GET['word'];` show you?

Comment: thanks for your answers, 1- No, nothing else . 2- Index of domain 3- When i want to open the subdomain, nothing opens (Server not found error)

Comment: **Server not found** simply meant you don't even have DNS setup for `test.example.com`. Can you even ping `test.example.com`?

Comment: the main address can be opened (example.com) But the virtual subdomain can't be found. also i can't ping to subdomain, but i can open the main url.

Comment: Well then you've some confusion about this whole thing. You need to first create DNS entry for your virtual sub domain then only rewrite rule can help you.

Comment: Thanks, You mean i have to set dns record for every every one? Is there any way to not need this? for example having unlimited and dynamic sub domains?

Comment: You can create wildcard sub domains. You need to ask your hosting provider how to do this.